# jQueryfy custom event creation code

Tags: jquery

Out of curiosity, how can I jQueryfy the below event generation code

```
var newevent = document.createEvent("Event");
newevent.initEvent("fly", true, true);
this.dispatchEvent(newevent);
```

where `this` points to the element currently selected.

Note: there is something wrong with my SO editor right now, as I cannot see the tools to format, or preview. Will format once it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use [**`.trigger()`**](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$(this).trigger('fly');
// or since jQuery 1.6 you can pass an object to `jQuery.Event` to set 
// properties
$(this).trigger(jQuery.Event('fly', {/* options here */}));
```

But I'm not sure if it also triggers event handlers that are not bound via jQuery.